# Change route without reloading page with Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Whenever the user clicks on the continue button, a function is fired and in that function, I call:

`push("/signup/page-2", undefined, { shallow: true });`

All dynamic routes that looks like `/signup/[page].js` that returns `<Component />`

I also have a `/signup/index.js` that returns `<Component />`

The Problem is:

The page reloads and all state is cleared each time `push("/signup/page-2", undefined, { shallow: true });` is called.

It's also worth mentioning that this app was a CRA with react-router-dom app that was converted to a next.js app

Comment: Why not just use ```history.push``` from ```react-router-dom```?  I have used this in all of my applications and the page does not reload on route change.

Comment: It's a next.js application

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You got it all wrong about [`shallow-routing`](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/shallow-routing). Shallow-routing works for the **same page URL** and generally, you will update the query string parameters for the same page and the updated value of query params will be available through the `router`.

`router.push('/signup/[page]', '/signup/page-1')` will push the new URL path and will navigate to a complete different page from `/signup/`. That is why shallow-routing doesn't work here and the `state` value resets.

In the pages directory `/signup/[page].js` and `/signup/index.js` are two completely different files in the file system. If you try to navigate between them with shallow-routing it will not work.

**Solution**

You don't need another dynamic route like `/signup/[page]` here, you can update the `page` param through query string and keep the same URL path. In `/signup/index.js` page you can get the updated value of the query param and work on it.

```
router.push({
   pathname: '/signup',
   query: {
      pageId: "page-1"  // update the query param
   }
}, undefined, { shallow: true})


// you have access to the updated value of pageId through router.query.pageId

const currPage = router.query.pageId
```

Comment: well explanation. But if i do this. It  will re render every components on that route. which i dont want.

Comment: Same, it still re-renders the page and all the components

Comment: I feel like the `useEffect` is causing my issues. It looks like only components tied to update on `useEffect` refresh. I'm really struggling with implementing a list view and details view setup like Asana's

Answer (score 4):

Ignore next router for this task, just use JavaScript to change the URL instead - components will not reload or be affected.

`window.history.pushState(null, 'Page Title', '/newUrl');`
(null is stateData).

For example:
You are on a users profile page `localhost.com/john` and you click on their post with the id `13983`:

```
function onPostClicked(post){
  showPost(post);
  window.history.pushState(null, 'Post by John', '/john/p/13983');
}
```

Then when they click away from the post you can return back to the original URL:

```
function onPostClosed(){
  hidePost();
  window.history.pushState(null, 'John', '/john');
}
```

Comment: This is perfect, thanks so much!! Works well when wanting to open a modal and change the URL for the user to copy, but not actually redirect the user

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering if this was the way to do it, and it was.